Nuxt 2 serve static image from another directory
I have redesigned my website to use Nuxt instead of Django and, as a result, there are some images that our email signatures use which no longer exist.
For example:-
https://example.com/media/logo.png used to exist in the Django site but I haven't got it in the new site.
I can see that I can serve static images with Nuxt (I'm using Nuxt 2, by the way) but the path for those will be:-
https://example.com/static/logo.png
Is there any way for me to serve the same image at the same URL with Nuxt 2? Otherwise I'm going to have to reconfigure all our email signatures to use the new path.
